# Javascript / Jquery Tree Travesal question

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tree, traversal

Suppose I have the following

```
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2
   <ul>
    <li>Sub Item</li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

This list is auto-generated by some other code (so adding exclusive id's/class' is out of the question.  Suppose I have some jquery code that states that if I mouseover an li, it gets a background color.  However, if I mouseover the "Sub Item" list item, "Item 2" will be highlighted as well.  How can I make it so that if the user mouses over "Sub Item" it only puts a background color on that and not on "Item 2" as well?

I also forgot to mention that I already have something like $("li").doSomething... on the page already...

Answer (score 2):

First you'll need a bit of CSS, a hover class and a background on the `<li>` elements, so the parent's background doesn't show up on children (because otherwise they have a transparent background, so whatever the parent has will show), like this:

```
​.hover { background: #ddd; }
li { background: #fff; }
```

Then you can use `mouseover` and `mouseout` (*not* `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` like [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) uses), like this:

```
$('li').mouseover(function(e){
    $(this).addClass("hover").parents().removeClass("hover");
    e.stopPropagation();
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
});​
```

[You can see a working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/WCupH/).  This uses [`.mouseover()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) and [`.mouseout()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) (so it fires when entering/leaving a child element, which `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` specifically won't).  On hover we apply the `hover` class to the current `<li>` and remove the class from any parents that might have it.  Also we prevent the event from bubbling with [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) so the same thing doesn't happen on this element's parents...just comment this out in the demo to see how this affects things :)

​

Comment: +1 - I got the question completely wrong. Here's a fiddle with your code http://jsfiddle.net/5LRKL/3/ for demonstration purposes

Comment: @Ben - Thanks, I linked a fiddle in the question though :)  I usually try to whenever it's demo-able :)

Answer (score 0):

try $('ul li li') as your selector. IE

```
ul li li:hover {background:#00F;}
```

EDIT

For a JQuery solution, it's the same selector. IE

`$('ul li li').css('background','#00F');